# Error then trying create-react-app( npm ERR! cb() never called! then trying create-react-app)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

Have some troubles then trying create react app

```
PS D:\Projects\Test> npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in D:\Projects\Test\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\semen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-05T05_29_35_153Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.
```

I  reinstalled nodejs few times. Made downgrade nodejs to 14.18.1 version. Tryed to used Yarn. But this soltushions dont work in my situation. I use Windows 10.
Thanks for help!

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: This is a several last strings of log. Before this error all goes succesful.
````
4423 timing npm Completed in 186464ms
4424 error cb() never called!
4425 error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
4426 error <https://npm.community>
```

Answer (score 1):

This error has happened to me before and I have followed these steps, I hope it works for you too.
The first thing you need to do is to uninstall the create-react-app and then npm install it again.
You can use these commands for uninstalling the create-react-app:
if you are using NPM:

```
 npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

if you are using Yarn:

```
yarn global remove create-react-app
```

for creating a new app you can use the following command:

```
npx create-react-app@latest your-project-name
```

You must notice that the create-react-app should not be installed globally as it is documented in [Create-React-app Docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#quick-start).

Also please note that it is safe to say, always use the LTS version of node (that is 16.13.2 at this time).

It should solve your problem with initiating a new react app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after I created my React app and couldn't install any more packages.

1. Try clearing your cache with `npm cache verify` or `npm cache clean --force`.
2. If that doesn't work, then try doing a clean install of npm using:`npm clean-install`.